# Bootstrap Multi-selection display two dropdown controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

@View,

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BreakdownType, "Related To", new { @class = "control-label required" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BreakdownType, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.BreakdownTypes as MultiSelectList, new
           {
               multiple = "multiple",
               @id = "ddlBreakDown",
               @Onchange = "multiChange()",
               data_placeholder = "--Select Related To--"
           })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BreakdownType)

            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Any one knows how its display two times?

Comment: can you check, both dropdown have same id or different ?. please post html code.

Comment: its define only one drpdown

Comment: can you select value from both dropdown?